# PHPExcel deletes old content

Tags: php, phpexcel

It might be very simple to do but I haven't found how yet.I tried to write content starting from the row that old data ends in existing xlsx file.What phpexcel does is that it deletes the old content even if i don't add anything to existing rows.I ve googled it a lot but couldn't find something that works.Thanks in advance!

```
<?php require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
echo date('H:i:s') , " Set document properties" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
echo date('H:i:s') , " Add some data" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B5', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C5', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D5', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'fffffffffffffffff')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'ffddddddddddd');

// Rename worksheet
echo date('H:i:s') , " Rename worksheet" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple2');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
?>
```

Comment: All you're doing is creating a new spreadheet, and then saving it.... you're not loading any existing spreadsheet to add new values to it.... simply showing the code for one of PHPExcel's existing examples to create and save a new spreadsheet file won't magically mutate into a block of code that updates an existing file by adding new rows

Comment: Write some code to load your existing spreadsheet file, find the last row number, add your new data from that point, then save the file

Comment: Thank you Mark.Ofcourse I tried to write new code, I just couldn't make it to work. I will try to load new sheet.

Comment: It would have helped if you'd posted the code that wasn't working, then I could look to see what you might be doing wrong

Comment: It's ok. I used $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("timer.xlsx"); and then I used $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn() and it worked. Your directions helped me a lot.Thank you!